# How to check if tcpdump catpured any packets?

Tags: bash, tcpdump

I'm trying to see if a system is up.  In order to achieve this I can use a tcpdump command to see the packets captured and use this to verify that a system is currently up.  However, I'm trying to incorporate this into a script and I'm not sure how to put that logic into a conditional.

I've tried using netcat but I can't seem to get that working at all so I'm only trying to use tcpdump at the moment because at least this works.

Here is the tcpdump command that works but I'm having trouble incorporating into an if conditional

```
tcpdump -i eth0 "udp port 69420"
```

Here is some pseudocode as to what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
if tcpdump captured any packets 
   echo "system is up"
```

Comment: It outputs to the screen by default (so is there anything there?) or you can use `-w file` to write the captured packages to `file` (or whatever name you give it). Then just check if `file` size is non-zero. (which you can do with `[ -s file ]`)

Comment: there is `-c` flag present in `tcpdump` command which allow user to provide number of packet capture . set it to 1 and put it in `if` condition.

Comment: like `if tcpdump -i eth0 "udp port 69420" -c 1 ;then
    echo "system is up"
fi`

Comment: Thanks PS that was what I was looking for.  David, I appreciate the answer, but unfortunately, that was one of the first things I attempted but I noticed that the file was being written with stuff even when 0 packets are recieved.

Comment: Glad the `-c 1` is what you were looking for (that is what you should use if you are just answering the question "are packets being captured"). The `-w file` presumes you have some desire to save what is captured, otherwise, it isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a blocking code and will keep listening to packets on the port till 1st packet is received.

```
if tcpdump -i eth0 "udp port 69420" -c 1 ;then
     echo "system is up"
 fi
```

> Usage: tcpdump [-aAdDeflLnNOpqRStuUvxX] **[-c count]** [ -C file_size ]
>                   [ -E algo:secret ] [ -F file ] [ -i interface ] [ -M secret ]
>                   [ -r file ] [ -s snaplen ] [ -T type ] [ -w file ]
>                   [ -W filecount ] [ -y datalinktype ] [ -Z user ]
>                   [ expression ]

PS: `tcpdump` is not typically used like this(continuous monitoring), it is a resource exhaustive, tool and should be used for debugging purposes.